# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server - build-essential install not possible

Tags: apt, package-management, held-packages

Have found this question multiple times on the forum, but none of the answers were serious enough.
So the problem with ubuntu 12.04. LTS server is that after a fresh install you can not install build-essential package.
This is what you get:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 build-essential : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                            libc-dev
                   Depends: g++ (>= 4:4.4.3) but it is not going to be installed
```

Things that DON'T help:

```
apt-get clean
apt-get update
apt-get -f install
apt-get upgrade
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get autoclean
apt-get --fix-missing install build-essential
```

apt does say that I have "held broken packages", but none of the above commands solves them. After running any of the above commands the summary at the bottom is all zeros (upgraded, newly installed, remove, not upgraded)

`uname -a` gives:

```
Linux sorrg01lin 3.11.0-15-generic #25~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 30 17:42:40 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

`lsb_release -a` gives:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

Comment: Yes, found that post too, but as I mentioned those commands do not help me. The only one I have not tried is dist-upgrade, because I want to stick with 12.04. But forgot to mention I have no X, and if possible don't want to install it just make apt work

Comment: sorry my mistake. found this post which cleared everything for me. http://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages

Comment: what part of that question answered it for you?  I have the same problem and it's not clear what the answer is

Comment: sorry don't quite remember the exact solution but running 'apt-get -f install' and 'dpkg --configure -a' helped for sure

Comment: in my case I was running from a Dockerfile, removing this line from it fixed for me `RUN echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe" > /etc/apt/sources.list`